# Letter only textbox in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

How would you write a regular expression in Visual Basic .NET to only accept upper and lower case letters on button click?

My text box can't accept numbers, blank spaces, or special characters.

Comment: I doubt you need any regex for it. Do you just want to let a user type only letters into your TextBox?

Comment: RegEx isn't necessary, but in case you're wondering, a regex for letters A-Z only, case insensitive, would be: `[A-Za-z]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to forbid a user type anything but letters into a text box field, just add the `KeyPress` event for your TextBox:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar <> vbBack And Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) = False Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[`Char.IsLetter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter(v=vs.110).aspx) is checking if the character typed is a letter. If the character the user typed is not a letter (`= False`), we omit passing it to the field by setting `e.Handled` to `True`.

Comment: The code works but  it wont let me delete any letters with backspace

Comment: @taji01 You just need to allow `vbBack`. For example change the statement inside the If/Then clause to `If e.KeyChar <> vbBack Then e.handled = True`

Comment: Never mind i figured it out thanks for helping on the first part